# Health Check Fail on Digital Ocean: Running Go server

Tags: docker, go, digital-ocean, health-check

When trying to deploy an app for a back-end server for a web application I am using a docker file to create my sever. Digital Ocean shows that my application fails health checks which to my understanding is just to check if my application is running or not.

When looking for responses to this issue I found that this is largely a port issue, thus I ensured that my port in digital ocean and in my code was the same and that at my root I needed to return a http status OK response.

I have ensured that my app spec and the exposed port in the docker file and the port serviced by the server is 8080.

The below is my server side code that would deal with the health check. Note: I have tried using the TCP and HTTP (on root and /health) options for the check and I am getting the same error.

```
err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":8080", getPath("cert.pem"), getPath("key.pem"), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Sever Error: %v", err)
    }

http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Println("You are visiting the foot backend")
        setCORS(w, r)

        // Handle OPTIONS for preflight
        if r.Method == http.MethodOptions {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println("in the main")
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "OK")

        responseText := "Hello, you are in the main"
        w.Write([]byte(responseText)) // Convert string to []byte
    })

    http.HandleFunc("/health", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        setCORS(w, r)

        // Handle OPTIONS for preflight
        if r.Method == http.MethodOptions {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
            return
        }

        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "OK")
```

The below is my Docker file:

```
FROM golang:1.21 AS builder
WORKDIR /app

RUN apt update

RUN apt install -y git ca-certificates \
    && update-ca-certificates \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy go mod and sum files
COPY go.mod go.sum ./

# Install dependencies
RUN go mod download

# Copy the source code
COPY ./Server ./Server
COPY main.go .
COPY ./GCalls ./GCalls
COPY ./Auth2 ./Auth2
COPY ./API ./API

EXPOSE 8080

# Run the binary
CMD ["go", "run", "main.go"]
```

I have exposed port 8080 which is what my app spec document states that it would connect to.

Is it not sufficient to expose the port in the docker file as above to allow the health check?
Is my handling of the health check on the server side not done correctly? I have understood that I just need to send back a status ok for the health check to pass.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: have you specified the health check endpoint on digital ocean config? what is the error message from digital ocean?

Comment: I have tried it both leaving it the standard TCP option and specified the root Http endpoint and another /health endpoint. The error message from digital ocean is: "Deploy Error: Health Checks". When looking at documentation for the reason for the error, digital ocean states: "your deploy failed because your container did not respond to health checks. If a health check is failing, that means that external traffic is not reaching your service at the expected HTTP route."

Comment: have you specified your health check endpoint in digital ocean? And to verify are you using Digital Ocean App Platform?

Comment: Yes I have verified both endpoint and that I am on the app platform.

Comment: I had a similar problem. The health check endpoint shown in the Digital Ocean UI shows that it will call your domain + the path to your health check endpoint. 
(ex. https://your.url-here.com/healthcheck)

But if you use any kind of host check (eg. for subdomains etc) this will fail. The first calls to your health check endpoint will most likely originate from an internal IP-address and not from the expected external host. In my case I had two subdomains being served by one binary - none of them reacted since the health check call was not for any of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why the health check was failing was because I was setting CORS Headers for the health check. This could be due to that the health check is coming from the same domain the app is deployed on (in this case digital ocean) as a result the health check was not able to get through.

The below is the code that I used to pass the health check:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Println("Health check request received")

        // Write an HTTP 200 OK status
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

        // Send a response body
        w.Write([]byte("OK"))
    })
```